# Having a table of contracts with activity periods, how do I calculate daily active contract counts?

Tags: oracle, optimization, common-table-expression

I have two tables:

- `contract(..., d1 date, d2 date, ...)` that describes some contracts and contains several millions (n*10^6!!!) of rows, `d1` & `d2` are the contract commencement and termination dates accordingly
- `calendar (d date)` that contains list of continuous dates (such a table is very useful for different purposes)

I need to calculate number of active contracts for each line of `calendar`, assuming that the contract is active if `contract.d1 <= calendar.d <= contract.d2`.

I'm now looking for the smartest way to solve this problem.

First, I've tried a brute force approach (just in case):

```
select  d, count(*) 
from    data 
join    calendar on d between d1 and d2
group   by d;
```

This query is obviously very heavy as it makes Oracle to work with a temporary table where each record from `contract` appears N times, where N is the number of days between `d1` and `d2` for this contract.

Another method was to avoid joining tables and counting contracts in the subselect instead, but it is also not so smart:

```
select  d,
       (select count(*) from contract where d between d1 and d2)
from    calendar;
```

In this case Oracle has to perform a huge subquery for each record of `calendar`.

Then I decided to transform my `contract` table into a CTE describing separate events:

- new contracts conclusion: this event fires at `d1` and increases the amount of contracts by 1, so I described it as `select d1, +1 from contract`
- contracts termination: this event fires ad `d2`+1 and decreases the amount of contracts by 1, so I described it as  `select d2+1, -1 from contract`

This new CTE allowes me to compute daily and running change in the overall amount of contracts. It is clear that the running change for each day is equal to the overall amount of contracts for that day, so I can immediately LEFT join the result to the calendar:

```
with 
    events (d,n) as (
        select d1,   +1 from contract -- new contracts
        union all
        select d2+1, -1 from contract -- terminated contracts
    ),
    counts_daily(d,n) as (
        select  d, sum(n)
        from    events   
        group   by d
    ),
    counts_running(d,n) as (
        select  d, sum(n) over (order by d)
        from    counts_daily
        order by d
    )
select  d, 
        nvl(n, lag(n ignore nulls) over(order by d)) n  
from    calendar 
left    join counts_running using(d)    
order   by d;
```

I use LEFT join as the `counts_running` exist only for dates where some contracts started or terminated. The `nvl(...,lag(...))` construction in the resulting select statement is necessary to obtain a values for calendar dates with no events, it takes the value from the last preceding date with events.

This query is much better than the previuos ones as it doesn't significantly increase the dimensions of the source data during computations.

I've also find the way to further improve this query and make it ~1.5..2 times faster. Still bearing in mind separate events instead of contracts, I didn't put them into a separate CTE but immediately performed an agregation allowing to obtain daily counts of +1 and -1 events. Everything else remained almost the same:

```
with 
    events_agg (d,n) as (
        select d1,    count(*) from contract  group by d1 -- new contracts
        union all
        select d2+1, -count(*) from contract group by d2 -- term. contracts
    ),
    counts_daily(d,n) as (
        select  d, sum(n)
        from    events_agg  
        group   by d
    ),
    counts_running(d,n) as (
        select  d, sum(n) over (order by d)
        from    counts_daily
        order by d
    )
select  d, 
        nvl(n, lag(n ignore nulls) over(order by d)) n  
from    calendar 
left    join counts_running using(d)    
order   by d;
```

So I just aggregated the events and let oracle UNION much smaller data sets.

**Would you suggest some other methods? Thanks.**

You may want to emulate the test data with the following CTE's:

```
with 
    --- TEST DATA EMULATION ---
    params as (
        select  trunc(sysdate) - 100  d0,                
                1e5                   number_of_contracts,
                100                   max_contract_term 
        from dual
    ),
    start_dates (d1) as(
        select  trunc(d0 + dbms_random.value(0, sysdate-d0)) d1 
                from params connect by level <= number_of_contracts
    ),
    contract (d1, d2) as ( 
        select  d1, 
                trunc(d1 + dbms_random.value(0, max_contract_term)) d2
        from    start_dates, params       
    ),
    calendar (d) as (
        select  d0 + level - 1 
        from    params
        connect by level <= sysdate - d0 + 1  
    ),
    --- END OF TEST DATA ---
    ------------------------
    ...
```

... or even place it into physical `calendar` and `contract` tables with suitable indexes.

Comment: I measured the times of these queries for test data, the first face over 1 second, the last about 100 ms. Basic question - is the time of 1 second really unsatisfactory? How often will this query be performed? 100 times a second ? Once a minute ? Once a day, or maybe once a month ? Is it worth investing time to expand this query, and make it more and more complicated only so that the client would only make it once a day and it lasts 100 ms instead of 2 seconds? 
More complicated = harder to maintain in the future. Some new programmer will have a hard time in two years to understand this query

Comment: It is several minutes vs 5 seconds on the production DB, so it does worth improvement. But to be clear, nobody is going to run this query as I have developed it just to satisfy my own curiosity ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You approach is fine, and I don't thing there is a fundamental better solution.
To get all the contract transactiona you must consider  at least twice each record in  `contract` table, which you are doing.

A subtle different possibility is instead of double scaning the table performing a single scan and join with a two record table containg teh activation and termination records.

```
with two as (
select 1 n from dual union all
select -1 n from dual),
contract_transactions as (
select 
case when n = 1 then c.d1 else c.d2+1 end as d,
n
from contract c
cross join two d)
select d, sum(n) n 
from contract_transactions
group by d
```

Instead of yours double `FULL TABLE SCAN`

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |          |  1528K|    13M|   107K  (1)| 00:25:06 |
|   1 |  UNION-ALL                  |          |       |       |            |          |
|   2 |   HASH GROUP BY             |          |   764K|  6715K| 53785   (1)| 00:12:33 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| CONTRACT |   764K|  6715K| 53767   (1)| 00:12:33 |
|   4 |   HASH GROUP BY             |          |   764K|  6715K| 53785   (1)| 00:12:33 |
|   5 |    TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| CONTRACT |   764K|  6715K| 53767   (1)| 00:12:33 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

there is only one `FULL TABLE SCAN`, but followed with a join the the two records table

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |          |  1528K|    30M|   107K  (1)| 00:25:07 |
|   1 |  HASH GROUP BY               |          |  1528K|    30M|   107K  (1)| 00:25:07 |
|   2 |   MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN       |          |  1528K|    30M|   107K  (1)| 00:25:06 |
|   3 |    VIEW                      |          |     2 |     6 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     UNION-ALL                |          |       |       |            |          |
|   5 |      FAST DUAL               |          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |      FAST DUAL               |          |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   7 |    BUFFER SORT               |          |   764K|    13M|   107K  (1)| 00:25:07 |
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL| CONTRACT |   764K|    13M| 53767   (1)| 00:12:33 |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I do not thing there will be relevant difference in performance (the same optinion is the CBO;).

For me it is more native to split the `contract` record in two *transactions*  using a join.

Comment: Thanks for you idea,  using a join really looks more accurate for me too.